# get data in json format between two mapping classes

Tags: java, json

I have mapping with class admin and class role I want to show the data od admin class in Json format but I have error Http 500 because this is a mapping between class admin and role how can I do this?

this is my `class Admin`

```
@Entity
public class Admin implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int idAdmin;

    private String email;   
    private String cin;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;

    private String loginAdmin;

    private String adresse;
    private Long tele;



    private String motPasse;
    private boolean actived;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idRole")
    private Role role;


    public Admin() {
        super();
    }

    public int getIdAdmin() {
        return idAdmin;
    }

    public void setIdAdmin(int idAdmin) {
        this.idAdmin = idAdmin;
    }



    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMotPasse() {
        return motPasse;
    }

    public void setMotPasse(String motPasse) {
        this.motPasse = motPasse;
    }

    public boolean isActived() {
        return actived;
    }

    public void setActived(boolean actived) {
        this.actived = actived;
    }

    public String getCin() {
        return cin;
    }

    public void setCin(String cin) {
        this.cin = cin;
    }


    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


    public String getLoginAdmin() {
        return loginAdmin;
    }

    public void setLoginAdmin(String loginAdmin) {
        this.loginAdmin = loginAdmin;
    }

    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }

    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }

    public Long getTele() {
        return tele;
    }

    public void setTele(Long tele) {
        this.tele = tele;
    }
}
```

And this is my role class

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idRole;
    private String roleName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role")
    private List<Admin> admin;

    public Role() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getIdRole() {
        return idRole;
    }

    public void setIdRole(Long idRole) {
        this.idRole = idRole;
    }

    public String getRoleName() {
        return roleName;
    }

    public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
        this.roleName = roleName;
    }


    public void setAdmin(List<Admin> admin) {
        this.admin = admin;
    }


    public List<Admin> getAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }
}
```

And this is my function in controller to show the data in json format

```
@RequestMapping(value =" /jsonPosts", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = 
"application/json")
 @ResponseBody
 public List<Admin> generateJSONPosts() {

    return adminService.selectAll();
 }
```

The problem is the mapping between role and admin

Comment: Excuse me, but i don't see mapping between Admin and Role entities.
I see two entities with relation.
Want you parse incoming json packet to Admin class?

Comment: sorry it's relation I want to get admin data in json format but I have error 500